# Arbitrary precision numbers and Javascript, Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, arbitrary-precision, autobean

This is not really a question as I do have a work around with the issue, but I thought I'd let everyone know because it may have quite a wide impact on the way people work with the Google Web Toolkit.

So one of the problem is with the way [Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) represents numbers in JSON. For example, `int myInt = 2` will become `"myInt":2` and `long myLong = 5432198765L` will become `"myLong":5432198765`, and `BigInteger myBI = 1310381093810938109481049128409487109378109248104098130981039810983` will become `"myBI":1310381093810938109481049128409487109378109248104098130981039810983`. While gson itself can deserialize this without a problem, the AutoBeans framework in GWT 2.4 in JSON will not like it. [Issue 6331](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6331) fixes it for the long representation in the upcoming GWT 2.5 release. However, [issue 7555](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7555) will not be resolved because of the way Javascript number precision works.

Thus, we will need to represent BigIntegers as Strings and it will work, e.g., `String myBIStr = new BigInteger("1310381093810938109481049128409487109378109248104098130981039810983").toString()` will be represented as `"myBIStr":"1310381093810938109481049128409487109378109248104098130981039810983"`. At the GWT end, this will result a String and we will have to build a BigInteger out of it.

It all makes perfect sense why Google will not resolve 7555, but that leads me to the real open question: how does one deal with high precision numbers in Javascript?

In general, if web-based Javascript and Google Web Toolkit front-ends are to challenge native front-ends, then there could be situations where we work with arbitrary precision numbers, instead of being restricted by about the 53-bit precision that [comment 3](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7555#c3) talks about. What's even worse is that doesn't this limitation also affect node.js or any other server side Javascript?

Is there a nice work around, especially one that uses or seamlessly works with Google Web Toolkit?

Answer (score 3):

GWT can do math on integers wider than 53 bits because it emulates Long (and BigInteger I think).  The math is slower, since it can't just use the native JS operations, but there's not a hard limit.

So, GWT has already implemented the workaround, and it's built in.  You just have to avoid passing numeric JSON when you need a big integer.

Comment: However, I tried to use BigIntegers in an implementation of a cryptosystem, but it failed. The same implementation works fine on standard Java though.

Comment: By "failed", I mean: for example, it stopped at the key generation phase. It just took ages to compute large primes, and eventually Javascript stopped responding. As a matter of fact, it failed even with a 128-bit public key cryptosystem. I noticed that BigInteger is supported by GWT, so I thought I could just work with them but I couldn't.

Comment: That is an inappropriate task for javascript. It's failing because it is very slow to work with large numbers, and you are doing a lot of operations on a lot of large numbers.

Comment: The JSBN library from Stanford implements big numbers optimised enough for Javascript. Here's an example cryptosystem using that: http://www.bitpuzzle.com/tmp/47252cb0ddcaa147/commit/demo/jspaillierdemo.html. I wonder why JSBN optimisations have not been added to GWT.